# altering arraylist index in java

Tags: java

let's say i have an array list containing this following:
id, x_coor, y_coor, signal.

the value of id, x_coor, and y_coor are from database and the signal value is generated randomly.

my question is how to reorder the index of the list based on the signal
example:

```
[0] -> 1, 200, 100, 41
[1] -> 2, 300, 100, 81
[2] -> 3, 100, 300, 20
.
.
.
```

i need that list to be

```
[0] -> 3, 100, 300, 20
[1] -> 1, 200, 100, 41
[2] -> 2, 300, 100, 81
.
.
.
```

can someone help? i'm new to java

Comment: Use the [sort() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Comment: What is type of your container? Is it array arrays of primitive type, or list of arrays, or list of lists, or maybe list of instances of your class? There are many duplicates for each of these cases so you need to give us more information so we could point you to right one.

Comment: you want something like Arrays.sort((Item one, Item two) -> one.signal - two.signal));    ... but you need to give more code if you want a better answer

Comment: @nikdeapen Instead of subtracting, you should use `Integer.compare()`, to prevent numeric overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a tuple-like POJO.

(If you are storing your data some other way, please let me know and I'll update this answer to reflect that.)

```
public class Tuple implements Comparable<Tuple> {
     private int id;
     private int x_coor;
     private int y_coor;
     private int signal;

     public int compareTo(Tuple t){
        return Integer.compare(this.signal,t.signal);
     }
}
```

This will make your Tuple's natural ordering be based on the value of signal.

Then you simply call `Collections.sort(list);` and it will sort you list based on this new natural ordering.

If you already have a natural ordering you would like to preserve (or would like to sort your `Tuple` objects two different ways in two different scenarios), you will need to implement a Comparator to add an additional ordering without destroying the original natural ordering.

[Here's a tutorial on using both the `Comparable` and `Comparator` inferfaces.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with the next algorithm:

- turn your List into an array.
- sort that array based on the x_coor.
- add all the array to a new List.

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Coordinates is your content " id, x_coor, y_coor, signal"
      List<Coordinates> randomSorted = getRamdomlyGeneratedList();

      Coordinates[] arrayToSort = randomSorted.toArray(new Coordinates[0]);

      Coordinates[] sortedArray = sort(arrayToSort);

      List<Coordinates> sortedList = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
      for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
          sortedList.add(sortedArray[i]);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Why not just sort the list itself? And what `sort()` method are you calling?

Comment: I actually liked your answer more thanks for the advise!